# Couldn't execute command: gnome-screensaver-command --lock Verify that this is a valid command

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and a very novice user.

From today, I'm suddenly experiencing this problem. If I press Ctrl+Alt+L to lock the PC, I find the following error message

> Couldn't execute command: gnome-screensaver-command --lock Verify that
>   this is a valid command

and PC doesn't get locked. If I try to lock from menu item "Lock Screen" in the power button at the top right corner of the screen, nothing happens.

Yesterday I updated and upgraded the OS. I think this is the first time I'm trying to lock the PC after update.

What's going on? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reinstalling the gnome screensaver by executing:
`sudo apt-get install  gnome-screensaver --reinstall`
and see if the command and lock is available again.